# Cognos Report not suppressing the prompt coming from unrendered prompt page

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi, cognos-11

I have three Prompt Pages.
On PromptPage1 - There is a checkbox (input parameter p1), based on which report decides whether report decides if PromptPage#2 is to be shown or not. Variable v1 has been created based on parameter p1 and is working fine correctly. If the p1 is not set, v1 helps hiding the PromptPage#2.
PromptPage#3 uses a Query which uses some parameters declared on PromptPage#2.
On Execution, report asks for these parameters though these are not mandatory. How to suppress the parameter prompts which are coming from a unrendered page(PromptPage2 in this case?

Comment: Most Cognos report development questions are more complex than people realize or are willing to fully describe. Posting actual code (the XML report spec) would go a long way to adding clarity.

Answer (score 0):

"Required" is set in two places.  The prompt can be required or not.  The filter can be required, optional, or disabled.  These need to match.  If the prompt is not required, the filter should be optional.  If the filter is required, Cognos will ask for a value.

Answer (score 0):

I added the prompts from other page on the bottom of the Prompt Page1 and set the box type to None for these to hide them. The report is behaving correctly now.
Thanks everyone for sharing thoughts